# What is the "real" MVC pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns

When searching for MVC explanations and tutorials on Google I went through all links in the first 4 pages (search-term: mvc php) and made notes. I found that MVC is explained in 4 different ways. I understand that in theory they all come down to the same thing but seeing as that most patterns in programming get different names I was wondering why these 4 distinctly different patterns are all know under the same name. (keeping in mind that a 5th pattern using the same methodology is called MVP).
The 4 patterns I found are (hope this comes across correctly as I am hopeless at ASCII art):

```
U --> C --> M --> V --> U


      V --> U
      ^
      |
U --> C <-> M


            U
            ^
            |
U --> C --> V <-> M


      M <-> V --> U
      ^     ^
      |     |
U --> C ----|
```

Where U = User

Comment: Do you have a specific problem about one or more of these patterns?  Can you ask about that?  Otherwise, this is merely semantics.

Comment: The second depiction makes the most sense to me.  The third and fourth look like nonsense, unless they're referring to a specific framework which uses models as viewmodel DTOs or something.  That's really the biggest variable I find in interpretations of the pattern.  Some people think "models" are the bare view-bound objects sent to the view.  Others think "models" are the rich domain objects which represent the business logic.  I'm in the latter camp.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: No specific examples or problem. And I do not understand how this is just 'semantics'? Each pattern seems to me a different way of implementation. If these 4 differences are semantic differences then MVP and MVVM are also be just semantic differences?

Comment: OK. What is your goal? If we knew that, perhaps we could better advise you. MVP and MVVM have specific use-cases.  So does MVC.

Comment: MVC is a buzzword [nowadays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549857/simple-php-mvc-framework). So the descriptions differ between actual MVC and Web/Faux-MVC naturally.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: My goal is to understand MVC pattern(s). The fact that MVC is explained differently by different people while no-one seems to explain why that is (in fact nobody seems to even hint that others explain it differently), is confusing to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC is a pattern which is adapted to the environments it's used in, as such there is no "real" MVC pattern, just the MVC pattern to use in the given environment.

MVC was originally developed in Smalltalk, but smalltalk is a unique language that offers facilities not available in most other languages.

The [wikipedia entry for MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Ok, so the fact that there are multiple patterns is simply because the 'original pattern' was never strictly defined and multiple schools of thought developed in different areas?

Comment: @Evert - No, it was defined quite well in the papers referenced in the wikipedia link.  But, different environments required modifying it to work in those situations.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It is strange (to me at least) that all pages I can find on the subject seems adamant to regard their pattern as the only one and simply ignore the others. But it is clear to me now.

Comment: Programmers pushing their platform of choice and putting down all the others?! NEVER!